# How to customize entry field in xamarin forms in windows phone

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I've been trying to customize the entry field so that i can apply corner radiusin windows phone but i've been searching how to apply style template in custom renderer .I've used Custom renderer for android and set the background but for windows i didnt find any way to do it.I dont want to use the extended entry from X labs.
Please suggest?
Below is my Custom Renderer:

```
public class CustomEntryRenderer : EntryRenderer
{
    protected override void  OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.Entry> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (this.Control == null) return;

        var border = new Border {
                    CornerRadius = new System.Windows.CornerRadius(10),
                    Background = new SolidColorBrush(System.Windows.Media.Color.FromArgb(255, 130, 186, 132)),
                    BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(System.Windows.Media.Color.FromArgb(255, 45, 176, 51)),
                    BorderThickness = new System.Windows.Thickness(0.8),

                };
    }
}
```

I'm searching out for an option so that I set the corner radius for entry field.

Comment: What does your custom render look like, we can use it as a starting point and take it from there.

Comment: Johan- I have added the code in the post

Comment: That renderer does nothing, you create a border but you do nothing with it.

Comment: Yeah that I know I've created the border but dont find any way to set it to the entry field.How can i apply it to entry field?

Comment: Any reason for using `OnElementChanged`?

Comment: As per Xamarin Docs this method is called when  the corresponding Xamarin Forms control is created and please let me know if I'm wrong or If there any other workaround to get rounded corners for entry field in windows phone?